# Get value from input tag within a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, for-loop

I have a small question: I want to get a one table value row by row my selected cell value. I use for loop for select each row.For loop is correct but I cannot see anything in alert.

My table is

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table id="abctable" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <th width="15%">Registered Agents</th>
        </thead>                                                                  
        <c:forEach items="${Agentsdetail}" var="Agent">
        <tr>                                                        
            <td><input type="text" id="a" value="${Agent.vatNumber}"></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to select this table cell value of each row to alert. I use this jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("abctable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            alert($('#userstable tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)').val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

The row count is successful and when run a program, it returns nothing in the alert. Please help me

Comment: the table id is "userstable" not "abctable"

Comment: I changed it..Then alert gives undifiened message..

Answer (score 1):

As MartinWebb said, the table id is "usertable" not "abctable"

But also the value you are looking for is on the input, not the table cell (td), so your selector is incomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("userstable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    alert($('#userstable tr:eq(1) td:eq(0) input').val());
  }
});
```

Comment: `val()` is applied to input. To get text `text()` is used.

Comment: I used it...But didnt get any value

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("abctable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       
        for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var a = $('#abctable tr:eq(i) td:eq(0)').text();
            alert(a);
            alert(i);
        }
    });
</script>

Comment: I used this cord data retreive when i add manual value to the tr ...It dosnt get the for loop i... Whats the error